# Android Studio: app manifest folder is gone

Tags: android, android-studio

Same Android Studio, same PC different projects - 
1) manifest xml is "visually accessible"
2) no even folder.. but it was..
I just set up GSON jar.. nothing more.. and by the way, even GSON is added to lib files, I still unable to refer to it from code..
Looks like it is not present for the development environment anyway.

[image]

UPDATE
I have done the next: recreated a new project, added all   files and then again added the GSON lib over Android Studio just following some instructions..
File / Modules / Add Dependency as Lib / then found that GSON at google and tried to set it into package.
Result the same: it says ERROR: Attribute "package" was already specified for element "manifest". And manifest itself is disappeared.
So many time spent for such small thing and still I am here.. no progress..

Comment: The image where manifest is not available has the incorrect project structure because the res folder is also named as resources! Create a new empty project add copy the java classes and files to it.

Comment: Ufff, it was already second time )). First time I was unable to open project tree tool window. I've made update, now this bug.. ok, thanks for your effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will this work for everyone, but I updated Android Studio, because Gson lib was just hot, and AStudio was updated half a year ago.. and it worked..
Also, don't follow some dark/old comments in the Net about how to install Gson.
Don't use download and manual edit of your manifest.. `DON'T TOUCH MANIFEST AT ALL.`

The real one is:

--->0. UPDATE Android Studio

1. File
2. Project Structure \ Dependencies \ +
3. [image: List item]
4. [image]
5. And you've done `Gson gson = new Gson();`